# CMake install files with symbolic links

Tags: cmake, boost

В проекте используется boost, библиотеки shared. При cmake install нужно, чтобы нужные библиотеки с symlinks оказались в директории, добавленной в rpath.

```
add_custom_command(...), add_custom_target(...), file(GLOB ...)
```

не подходят.

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:Boost::date_time> DESTINATION ${some_folder})
```

не копируют файлы, копируют symlinks без soname.

```
install(DIRECTORY $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Boost::date_time> DESTINATION ${some_folder} PATTERN "*date_time.so.*" PATTERN "something")
```

требуют написания слишком много pattern'ов.

Есть что-нибудь красивое для этой проблемы? wildcard для install(FILES ...) подошел бы, если был. Весь boost копировать не хочется, испольузуется около 10 либ.

Comment: а зачем вам копировать эти либы?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду сделать `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` или подобное, то это имеет мысто быть. Но мой случай - когда от пользователя вообще ничего нельзя требовать.